# R: matrix double summation and normalization by vectors

Tags: r

I have this formula I derived and I want to implement in R.

[image]

This is the double loop way of doing it:

```
munew = 0
mu_normalizer = 0

for (j in 1:dim(x)[2] ) {
  for (i in 1:dim(x)[1] ) {
    munew = munew + (x[i,j]/(sigma_2[j] *omega_2[i]))
    }}
for (j in 1:dim(x)[2] ) {
  for (i in 1:dim(x)[1] ) {
    mu_normalizer = mu_normalizer + (1/(sigma_2[j] *omega_2[i]))
    }}

munew = munew/mu_normalizer
```

where sigma_2 and omega_2 are sigma^2 and omega^2 respectively.

What is the fastest way I can implement this in R?

Comment: post sample data. What is the current speed and why is it not sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `outer` (or its `%o%`) is helpful:

```
x = matrix(sample(1:3, 20, T), 5)
sigma_2 = runif(4)
omega_2 = runif(5)
munew = 0
mu_normalizer = 0

for (j in 1:dim(x)[2] ) {
  for (i in 1:dim(x)[1] ) {
    munew = munew + (x[i,j]/(sigma_2[j] *omega_2[i]))
    }}
munew
#[1] 445.5648
sum(x / (omega_2 %o% sigma_2))
#[1] 445.5648

for (j in 1:dim(x)[2] ) {
  for (i in 1:dim(x)[1] ) {
    mu_normalizer = mu_normalizer + (1/(sigma_2[j] *omega_2[i]))
    }}
mu_normalizer
#[1] 201.6099
sum(1 / (omega_2 %o% sigma_2))
#[1] 201.6099

munew/mu_normalizer
#[1] 2.210034
sum(x / (omega_2 %o% sigma_2)) / sum(1 / (omega_2 %o% sigma_2)) #this is the actual answer
#[1] 2.210034
```